# Problema Spinner Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Tengo un problema con un `Spinner` de `Android Studio`, pude lograr que tomara unas opciones con `StringRequest` haciendo una peticion `POST` y obteniendo los datos por `JSON`, asi alimentaba un array y con un `ArrayAdapter` colocar estas opciones en el Spinner, todo eso esta bien, el problema es que el `Spinner` no esta tomando ningún text inicial, y si selecciono una opción tampoco la ocupa el `spinner`, no se si me faltara una opción XML o el problema es netamente de `JAVA` espero puedan ayudarme, acá les dejo el código que utilizo:

Spinner en el XML:

```
    <Spinner
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/spinticket"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textct"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >
    </Spinner>
```

mi código de Java (Activity):

```
 final String idCliente = sharedPreferences.getInt("logged",0)+"";

 cats = new ArrayList<>();

  String url = "http://192.168.1.98/qrcode/getcat.php";

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(response);
                    JSONArray jsonArr = jsonObj.getJSONArray("response");

                    for(int a = 0; a<=jsonArr.length()-1;a++){
                        JSONObject jsonItem = (JSONObject) jsonArr.get(a);
                        cats.add(jsonItem.getString("categoria"));
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        }){
          protected Map<String, String> getParams(){


              Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
              params.put("idCliente",idCliente);
              return params;
          }
        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

 tv = findViewById(id.tvspin);

        spinAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,cats);

        spinAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        spin = findViewById(id.spinticket);

        spin.setAdapter(spinAdapter);
```

---

este es el JSON de la respuesta:

```
{"response":[{"categoria":"Preguntas Frecuentes"},{"categoria":"Soporte Tecnico"},{"categoria":"Departamento de Finanzas"},{"categoria":"Reporte"}]}
```

aca una imagen de como me sale el spinner cuando le doy click

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y aca una imagen cuando selecciono cualquier item...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Te sugiero indiques que recibes en el método onResponse(String response) como valor de "response".

Comment: un JSON, el problema no es el StringRequest sino el spinner que no muestra ninguna opcion seleccionada, osea muestra las opciones pero las selecciono y sigue en blanco.. este es el JSON: {"response":[{"1":"Anyelber Boscan","2":"Promoci\u00f3n","3":"invierte ahora y gana un 20% de cargo adicional","4":"2019-08-02"},{"1":"Anyelber Boscan","2":"Mantenimiento","3":"Se realizara un mantenimiento el 05\/08\/2019 para mejora la plataforma.","4":"2019-08-02"}]}

Comment: No existe un valor de "categoria" por eso no se llena el ArrayList con los valores para el Spinner, revisa mi respuesta.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Curiosamente no me seleccionaba la opción cuando cargaba estos datos de la base de datos,

pero antes de cargar estos datos de base de datos le agregue una opcion estatica...

```
cats.add("Seleccione una categoria");
```

y ahora si funciona perfectamente. gracias a los que trataron de ayudar.

Comment: Esto no creo que sea la solución al problema, aquí solo estas agregando otro elemento al Array List, me parece que tienes un texto vacio como primer elemento, para esto usa   spinner.setSelection(1); para que defina como texto inicial "Preguntas frecuentes", revisa mi actualización @AnySlehider

Answer (score 2):

Si tu json que obtienes de la respuesta es:

```
 {
    "response": [{
        "1": "Anyelber Boscan",
        "2": "Promoci\u00f3n",
        "3": "invierte ahora y gana un 20% de cargo adicional",
        "4": "2019-08-02"
    }, {
        "1": "Anyelber Boscan",
        "2": "Mantenimiento",
        "3": "Se realizara un mantenimiento el 05\/08\/2019 para mejora la plataforma.",
        "4": "2019-08-02"
    }]
 }
```

**el problema es que el parser esta tratando de obtener un valor "categoria" el cual no existe** , por lo tanto no llena el `ArrayList` `cats` que sirve para alimentar tu `Spinner`.

Trata obteniendo el valor de "2" que al parecer son las categorías y tu Spinner se llenara con estos valores (`[Promoción, Mantenimiento]`).

```
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(response);
            JSONArray jsonArr = jsonObj.getJSONArray("response");

            for(int a = 0; a<=jsonArr.length()-1;a++){
                JSONObject jsonItem = (JSONObject) jsonArr.get(a);
                //cats.add(jsonItem.getString("categoria"));
                 cats.add(jsonItem.getString("2"));
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

---

Actualización:

Si tu json tiene esta estructura debe funcionar correctamente el parser,

```
 {
    "response": [{
        "categoria": "Preguntas Frecuentes"
    }, {
        "categoria": "Soporte Tecnico"
    }, {
        "categoria": "Departamento de Finanzas"
    }, {
        "categoria": "Reporte"
    }]
 }
```

**pero si deseas que se muestre un texto inicial, usa el método `setSelection(indice)` , donde defines el indice del elemento que deseas mostrar al inicio.**

```
spinner.setSelection(lastIndex);
```

en este caso si tienes un texto en blanco como primer elemento y deseas mostrar el siguiente elemento usa:

```
spinner.setSelection(1);
```

Comment: perdon, el json es este: {"response":[{"categoria":"Preguntas Frecuentes"},{"categoria":"Soporte Tecnico"},{"categoria":"Departamento de Finanzas"},{"categoria":"Reporte"}]}       copie el de otro archivo, el StringRequest se trae los datos bien, el array se alimenta alli no esta el problema.

Answer (score 0):

Coloca este código

```
spin.setAdapter(spinAdapter)
```

luego del bucle FOR en "on response"

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y describe cómo este código responde a la pregunta. Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.